# AngularJs - a diretiva ng-class não está funcionando

Tags: javascript, angularjs, front-end, angularjs-directives

Estou tentando aplicar essa classe a está  quando eu rolo a página para fixar meu menu no topo da tela, mas a classe não está sendo setada:

```
<div class="page-header-menu" ng-class="{'fixed':(document.documentElement.scrollTop > 74)}">
    <!-- aplicação-->
</div>
```

Estou utilizando a versão 1.2.30.
 
Meus agradecimentos a quem responder.

Comment: Colocar isso aqui **`{{(document.documentElement.scrollTop > 74)}}`**, na view, funciona? Digo, mostra algo?

Comment: cria na sua controller uma variavel $scope que carrega o resultado de `document.documentElement.scrollTop` e faz a condicional do ng-class usando esta variável. comigo funcionou assim.

Answer (score 0):

Não é uma boa prática acessar o `document` diretamente dentro de um componente angular, mas para resolver seu problema segue exemplo de código abaixo.

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.a = 'aaa';
  $scope.fixElement = function(){
    return document.documentElement.scrollTop > 74
  }
})
```

```css
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  color: red;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-class="{'fixed': fixElement()}">{{a}}</div>
</div>
```